# How to display post title on top of image with Genesis Featured Posts

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

With Genesis Featured Posts the post title displays below the image. I need to display it above the image. I have tried jquery but it places all post titles above each post image so each image has all 9 titles above it. I have way too many hours into this for what should be easy. I need to accomplish this without changing the regular post layout. The area in question is the Blog area near the bottom of the page with the dark blue background. Thank you in advance.

A link to the page http://bit.ly/1fjXY9F

Answer (score 0):

when blog section comes from posts then check the content.php in active particular theme.
and modify the html code

```
    <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php else : ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h1>
    <?php endif; // is_single() ?>

    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php twentythirteen_entry_meta(); ?>
        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

use this code above the thumbnail image.